# wso2 identity server client application

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

how do i write a client application to test OAuth 2.0? I found documentation on configuring wso2 identity server, but did not find any docs on where to download oauth client libraries and how to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple HTTP client to call OAuth end points.  For this, You can use the Apache HTTP client library. And also, you can use amber oauth client library to build messages easily. (for authorization code grant type, you may need some browser directs). WSO2 Identity server has some sample, that can try out four main grant types. You can find the sample web application code from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/4.6.0/modules/samples/oauth2/playground2/). I guess, if you can go through this code, you can see how client side has been implemented.